# Confounding Cocoa problem — program hangs unless there’s an unrecognised method call

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, unrecognized-selector

Bear with me, this one is hard to explain. I hope some hero out there knows what’s going on here. Some history needed;

One of my cocoa objects, “Ball” represents a small graphic. It only makes sense within a view. In some of the Ball’s methods, it asks the view to redraw. Most importantly, it asks the view to redraw whenever the Ball’s position parameter is set. This is achieved in the setter.

Here’s the mouthful, as suggested:

In View.m

```
- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    if (![runnerPath isEmpty]) {
        [walkPath removeAllPoints];
        [walkPath appendBezierPath:runnerPath];
        [runnerPath removeAllPoints];

        [[self held] setStep:0];
        [[self held] setPath:walkPath];
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:[self held] selector:@selector(pace) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        }
}
```

In Ball.m

```
 - (void)pace { 
    CGFloat juice = 10;
    BOOL loop = YES;

    while (loop) {
        if ([self step] == [[self path] elementCount]) {
            if ([[self timer] isValid]) {
                [[self timer] invalidate];
            }
            [[self path] removeAllPoints];
//          @throw([NSException exceptionWithName:@"test" reason:@"reason" userInfo:nil]);
        }

        if (loop) {
            CGFloat distance;
            NSPoint stepPoint;

            if ([[self path] elementCount] > 0) {
                NSPoint returnPoints[2];
                [[self path] elementAtIndex:[self step] associatedPoints:returnPoints];
                stepPoint = returnPoints[0];
                distance = pixelDistance([self position], stepPoint);
            }

            if (distance <= juice) {
                [self setPosition:stepPoint];
                if (distance < juice) {
                    juice -= distance;
                    loop = YES;
                    [self setStep:[self step]+1];
                } else {
                    loop = NO;
                }
            } else {            
                NSPoint cutPoint = moveAlongBetween([self position], stepPoint, juice);
                [self setPosition:cutPoint];

                loop = NO;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried running your app in the debugger and then pausing execution when the freeze happens and examining the call stack?

Comment: What optimization level are you using? I'm wondering if the empty loop with the use of `-allObjects` is being removed by the compiler.

Comment: Looking at the debugger now, and googling frenetically. I’m embarrassingly unfamiliar with how this works. Thanks for your help, anyway. I’ll see what I can make of the call stack.

Comment: Maybe you could reduce the text of the original question, so that it would only include the source code of the function in which you think the freeze happens + the description of the freeze behavior. It could be something very simple.

Comment: @Rick: thanks for the info, I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you also tell how you handle exceptions? since normally an unrecognized selector will end your program. Maybe you need an exception rather than an unrecognized selector. Try:

```
@throw([NSException exceptionWithName:@"test" reason:@"reason" userInfo:nil]);
```

If this would fix it as well, you're doing something after this code which freezes the app.

**edit:** thanks for the code update.

There's some weird stuff going on here! I'm not going to rewrite the whole thing, so here's some pointers:

- first of all: you're looping inside some routine that is called from a timer loop. Is that intended? There is no way to pause execution within that `while()` loop, so it will happen in a blink anyway. You would need to keep some state information in the class. E.g. adding a loop counter every time `pace` is called.
- second: if you start a timer, it will call your selector with the timer as an argument. So define the function as `-(void)pace:(NSTimer*)timer`, and use `timer`, not `[self timer]` (the latter will not be your timer anyway, if you don't assign it!)
- third: you're firing 100 times a second. That is a lot, and presumably higher than the refresh rate of any device you're writing this for. I think 20/sec is enough.
- fourth: to be sure, if you change it to `-(void)pace:(NSTimer*)timer`, don't forget to use `@selector(pace:)` (i.e. don't forget the **`:`**)

fix those things, and if it's still broken, update your question again and put in comment so we will know. Good luck!

Comment: The @throw statement also does it. I’m a bit of a novice, but I take it I should look for the error further down the line? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok then there are 2 options: 1) you bail out in time to not freeze the app further down the road 2) your exception handling does something else which prevents freezing. Luckily there's a great way to bail the function out *without* the exception, called `return;`. If the code doesn't freeze then, it must be something past this point in the same function. If it does freeze, you either depend on some magic happening in the exception handling, *or* there's something buggy happening past the point where you call this function from, before handling the exception.

Comment: but this is getting a little out of hand. To cut things short: are you very sure you're not setting `self.position = ...;` from within the setter? Please `NSLog("something");` in `setPosition` to see if you're not in an infinite loop.

Comment: (or, as an alternative: you're not doing `self.something = ...;` which does `self.position = ...;`, introducing a loop?)

Comment: Sweet — now that I used the timer from the argument, everything works without the exception. I added a return; to make it all neater.

The weird loop is intended, and uses as loop counter the “step” ivar. This is of course not very elegant, but the code is really just a prototype, and the interesting bit is elsewhere. The same goes for the overambitious firing interval — I’ve been messing around with the values to see if some interface things can keep up.

Anyway, great help. Every time I ask things here, it ends up brightening the day. Can’t thank you enough.

Comment: Btw, I used to assign the timer to an ivar, but got rid of that. Yeah, that was stupid, and probably what got me into this mess.

Comment: @Rick: now I see, a `[self setStep:[self step]+1];`, buried deep down. Why not make it an int and just `step++`? anyway, glad I could be of help!

Answer (score 1):

Try calling

```
for (NSView *each in [self views]) {
    ...
}
```

I'm assuming that `views` is an array, so fast enumeration applies to it directly and there is no need to call allObjects.

A couple of other points.

1. Have you set a Global breakpoint of objc_exception_throw? This will apply to all Xcode projects and is so useful I'm surprised it isn't set by default.
2. You say you looked at the Console for errors. I take it, then, that you didn't set a breakpoint on the code and step into it to see exactly what is happening when your execution reaches that point? Have a look at the [Xcode Debugging Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/200-Managing_Program_Execution/program_execution.html)

Comment: +1 He says `views` is an NSSet, so fast enumeration applies there too.

Comment: How has this anything to do with the app freeze?

Comment: @NRA - If you set a breakpoint and step into the code, you will be able to see the state of local and global variables and find out where your hang is occurring. I've added a link to my answer.